# onDataChange() is not being called when offline in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

(Sorry for my bad English) There is a `listView` which need to be populate by `FirebaseDatabase` which has offline mode enabled with `setPersistenceEnabled(true)`. `listView` is populating perfectly in online mode, but in offline mode `listView` is not populating until there is a view in the `listView` which has been synchronized online before.

I mean, if i use application in offline mode from very first time after installation  to add first data in offline mode(There is no view in `listView` yet), the `offline cache` is being written but the `onDataChange` is not being fired and after that if application get online the `listView` is automatically being populated with the data i entered before in offline mode, after that `listView` is working fine even in offline mode too.

The code is :

```
private void getAndSetItem(){

        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference itemReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("groups").child(intent.getStringExtra("groupID"))
                .child("items").child(hiddenUserID);
        itemReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ArrayList<Item> itemsArray = new ArrayList<Item>();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    itemsArray.add(snapshot.getValue(Item.class));
                }
                ItemExtractor itemExtractor = new ItemExtractor(itemsArray);
                CustomAdapterForItemList adapter = new CustomAdapterForItemList(ItemPage.this, itemExtractor.getItemNameList(),
                        itemExtractor.getItemPriceList(), itemExtractor.getItemQuantity(), itemExtractor.getDate());
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change this behaviour. For an application which uses Firebase database to work offline, you need to connect that app to Firebase at least once. You cannot download the app, go offline and use the database as you were online.

This is happening because `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` needs a Firebase connection in the first place. So connecting you app to Firebase and using `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` is enabeling your app to work offline, which means that Firebase will create it's own internal (local) version of the database.

After creating that local copy, when data is updated, it is first written to this local version of the database. As a result, all writes to Firebase will trigger local events immediately, before any data has even been written to the server. This means that the app will remain responsive regardless of Internet connectivity.
Once the Internet connectivity is reestablished, you'll receive the appropriate current server state. The Firebase client synchronizes that data with the Firebase servers and with other clients that are using the same database.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about this.

Comment: You're welcome Nishant Bhakta! If you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: Would you please tell me, how can i get rid of this. any suggestion. i can not leave this.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot. You need to get online at least once in order to create the local version of ypur database. So the flow needs to be like this: Download App -> Connect  to Internet -> Create Local Database Copy (it is made automatically) -> Go offline.

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution for this. i just called addListenerForSingleValueEvent with blank onDataChange() for that reference in MainActivity and now it is working :)

Answer (score 0):

Call `itemReference.keepSynced(true)`